# Identify 'ng-reflect-opened' by using selenium web driver

Tags: angularjs, selenium, selenium-webdriver, ui-automation

I am trying to get the value of 'ng-reflect-opened', by this value i can assert whether on click of side navigation, left menu is visible or not

```
<mat-sidenav class="mat-elevation-z8 mat-drawer mat-sidenav ng-tns-c5-0 ng-trigger ng-trigger-transform mat-drawer-side" fixedtopgap="56" tabindex="-1" ng-reflect-mode="side" ng-reflect-opened="true" ng-reflect-fixed-in-viewport="false" ng-reflect-fixed-top-gap="56" style="transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px); visibility: visible;">
```

currently i am unable to get the value, as selenium do not support this property of ng model .. i am new to selenium and want to assert the test case on click action of side navigation button .. which is placed in the header section of the page

when button is clicked left navigation menu is not visible .. [image: snapshot attached]

When button is clicked again ..left navigation menu is displayed ..[image: [snapshot]]

Answer (score 0):

The question doesn't mentions the Selenium Client/bindings to be used. Though its an **`Angular Element`** still we must be able to extract the **`ng-reflect-opened`** attribute through the following line of **`Java`** code :

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//mat-sidenav[@class='mat-elevation-z8 mat-drawer mat-sidenav ng-tns-c5-0 ng-trigger ng-trigger-transform mat-drawer-side']")).getAttribute("ng-reflect-opened");
```